# ui-sref open with new tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to open ui-sref in new tab, noted that i don't want to call it from controller. How to do from view end?

```
   <div class="col-md-12  text-right wow fadeInUp"> 
        <!-- submit button -->
                <button ui-sref="app.blogs" target="_blank" class="btn btn-black " id="form-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">See all Blogs</button>
         <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open a ui-sref from the view you can use target="_blank", but note that the *button element does not support target*. Change your button into an anchor tag.

```
<a ui-sref="app.blogs" target="_blank">See all blogs</a>
```

If you want to continue to use the button element, I believe you need to use the controller.

Answer (score 0):

adding logic to view is not a good practice, however,

- you can add some function to your controller and use it in your view(in view you don't have access to WINDOW/DOCUMENT or any other variable/function which is not part of scope)
- or you can use HTML tags same as @Zahid Rahman answer(like target="_blank")

but I really recommend you to use a controller for UI logic and services for general logics and API calls or sharing data between controllers